# Should I test every single method in Integration Test?

Tags: python, unit-testing, integration-testing

I often find methods that combine 2 responsibilities into 1 like the CreateOrUpdate method, I was wondering, should I test every method in Integration Test? isn't it when we test this method is already testing everything inside it? we can just create 2 test cases, 1 for update and 1 for create?

Here is my source code:

```py
def distribute_transaction(self,
        depth_purchase_request_id: int,
        bulk_reference_lead_id: int,
        customer_requested: Customer,
        r123_depth_purchase: DepthPurchaseRequestViewModel
    ):
    depth_bulk_purchases = self._depth_bulk_purchase_repo.get_all_by_depth_purchase_id(depth_purchase_request_id)
    
    for depth_bulk_purchase in depth_bulk_purchases:    
        if depth_bulk_purchase.customer_id == customer_requested.id:
            continue
        lead_depth_bulk_purchase_exists = self._lead_depth_bulk_purchase_repo.get_by_depth_bulk_purchase(depth_bulk_purchase.id)
        
        if not lead_depth_bulk_purchase_exists:
            self.create_lead_and_transaction(
                    depth_bulk_purchase,
                    bulk_reference_lead_id,
                    LeadStageConstants.PACKAGE_ACTIVE,
                    r123_depth_purchase)
        else:
            self.update_lead_and_transaction(
                    depth_bulk_purchase,
                    LeadStageConstants.PACKAGE_ACTIVE,
                    r123_depth_purchase,
                    lead_depth_bulk_purchase_exists)

def create_lead_and_transaction(...):
    ...
def update_lead_and_transaction(...):
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

no integration testing is when you group errors and non-errors and test them as group, solving each error separately to see if its not the only thing causing an error, I would recommend looking up the ISTQB standards of Integration Testing.